# Pandas: Selecting column from data frame

Tags: python, pandas

Pandas beginner here. I'm looking to return a full column's data and I've seen a couple of different methods for this.

What is the difference between the two entries below, if any? It looks like they return the same thing.

loansData['int_rate']

loansData.int_rate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latter is basically syntactic sugar for the former. There are (at least) a couple of gotchas:

- If the name of the column is not a valid Python identifier (e.g., if the column name is `my column name?!`, you must use the former.
- Somewhat surprisingly, **you can only use the former form to completely correctly add a new column** (see, e.g., [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7175)).

**Example for latter statement:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(4)})
df.b = range(4)
>> df.columns
Index([u'a'], dtype='object')
```

For some reason, though, `df.b` returns the correct results.

Comment: Your last statement is untrue unless you can provide sample code

Comment: Will do so. <padding>

Comment: I think the issue you link to is surprising but I'd never try that, thanks for the link though

Comment: @EdChum I remembered there was a problem with it - see above. I've had loads of trouble with this in the past.

Comment: Yeah it's unclear what the rules are so I always avoid it now

Answer (score 2):

They do return the same thing.  The column names in pandas are akin to dictionary keys that refer to a series.  The column names themselves are named attributes that are part of the dataframe object.

The first method is preferred as it allows for spaces and other illegal operators.

For a more complete explanation, I recommend you take a look at this article:
http://byumcl.bitbucket.org/bootcamp2013/labs/pd_types.html#pandas-types

Search  'Access using dict notation'  to find the examples where they show that these two methods return identical values.

Comment: the article is also a good way to build context about what pandas is and how it thinks :)

Answer (score 1):

They're the same but for me the first method handles spaces in column names and illegal characters so is preferred, example:

```
In [115]:

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['a', ' a', '1a'])
df
Out[115]:
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [a,  a, 1a]
Index: []

In [116]:

print(df.a) # works
print([' a']) # works
print(df.1a) # error
  File "<ipython-input-116-4fa4129a400e>", line 3
    print(df.1a)
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Really when you use dot `.` it's trying to find a key as an attribute, if for some reason you have used column names that match an attribute then using dot will not do what you expect.

Example:

```
In [121]:

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index'], data = np.random.randn(3))
df
Out[121]:
      index
0  0.062698
1 -1.066654
2 -1.560549
In [122]:

df.index
Out[122]:
Int64Index([0, 1, 2], dtype='int64')
```

The above has now shown the index as opposed to the column 'index'

Answer (score 0):

In case if you are working on any ML projects and you want to extract feature and target variables separately and need to have them separably.
Below code will be useful: This is selecting features through indexing as a list and applying them to the dataframe. in this code data is DF.

```
len_col=len(data.columns)
total_col=list(data.columns)
Target_col_Y=total_col[-1]
Feature_col_X=total_col[0:-1]
print('The dependent variable is')
print(Target_col_Y)
print('The independent variables are')
print(Feature_col_X)
```

## The output for the same can be obtained as given below:

```
The dependent variable is
output
The independent variables are
['age', 'job', 'marital', 'education','day_of_week', ... etc]
```